# Laravel: How to get single pivot row by key id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have a many-to-many relation set on my **User** and **Notification** Eloquent models. This way I can access the pivot table - **user_notifications** - as follows:

```
$user = User::find(1);
foreach ($user->notifications() as $n) {
    echo $n->pivot->created_at;
}
```

This will give me all `created_at` field values from the pivot table, for the user of ID = 1.

What if I need **only one** pivot row, let's say the one with **notification_id = 2**? Is there a way to combine `pivot` with `where` or `has`? Can it be done without looping through `$user->notifications()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a `where` clause on the relationship:

```
$notification = $user->notifications()->where('notification_id', 2)->first();
echo $notification->pivot->created_at;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also directly use `find` method.

```
$notification = $user->notifications()->find(2);
echo $notification->pivot->created_at;
```

Answer (score 4):

I've been dealing with this, and lukasgeiter's answer is fine, until the weird case where you want to find a pivot row by **id** (if you set up a `$table->increments('id')` column on the pivot table. I do this sometimes, but a better solution is to use a dedicated model for the relationship (**Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models** @ https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

What you can do in this strange case:

```
$notification = $user->notifications()->having('pivot_id', 2)->first();
echo $notification->pivot->created_at;
```

You'll have to include `withPivot('id')` in your relationship method in the model. i.e.

```
function notifications() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Notification')->withPivot('id');
}
```

Comment: yo thanks man nice job